# Bootstrap 3 DatePicker not working after include to another page

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, datetimepicker

I tried to include Bootstrap 3 DatePicker to my php page.

This is my **date.php** code

```
<form>
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="row"> 

        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
        });

    });
```

and date.php include to rent.php page using

```
<?php $this->load->view('common/date'); ?>
```

I'm using Codeignaiter and all js files and css files import correctly..

any help please

Comment: #datetimepicker1 id is unique ?

Comment: see your firebug there is any error ?

Comment: if I load my date.php file separate, its working correctly but the issue is after including to another php file its not working

Comment: @JYoThI : there is error in my console its says `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: add jquery to your project

Comment: @madalin ivascu : its added correctly

Comment: add this line in your page and try again <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: I tried but same result.. its not working

Comment: show your full source here .

Comment: please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined

Comment: @JYoThI  : Thanks,I found the issue its overwriting with another jquery.